# Bubble sort does not seem to work-segmentation error

Tags: c

Hi there somehow my bubble sort that is suppose to work does not seem to work.Im not sure where the error is being caused.It is suppose to give me a sorted output list.It is giving me segmentation error and have been trying this for about 1 hr.Heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

 void sort(int [], int);
 void show(char *, int [], int);

int main(void)
{
int i, j, a[N];

srand(0);

for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    // initialise array (pseudo-randomly)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%100;
    }

    // display, sort, then re-display
    printf("Test #%d\n",j);
    show("Sorting", a, N);
    sort(a, N);
    show("Sorted ", a, N);
}   
return 0;
 }

// sort array using bubble sort
void sort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j, nswaps;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i--) {
        nswaps = 0;
        for (j = n-1; j > i; j--) {
        if (a[j] < a[j-1]) {
            int tmp;
            tmp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = tmp;
            nswaps++;
        }
    }
    if (nswaps == 1) break;
  }
}

// display array, preceded by label
void show(char *label, int a[], int n)
{
int i;
printf("%s:", label);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf(" %02d", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger or in a program like Valgrind? Valgrind is incredibly helpful at pinning down where memory errors are happening.

Comment: First `for` loop   `for (i = 0; i < n; i--)` -->    `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Please format your code if you want others to read it. Anyhow, learn to use a debugger and step through the program.

Comment: @F no I haven’t yet but I think I found the problem haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not technically sorting here.Instead of this `for (i = 0; i < n; i--)`, try `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`.This is because you are starting with `i=0` so in a FOR loop you need to increment i.